# Best Practice to Return the Control to Calling HTML Page After the Execution of Php Script/Function

Tags: php, html, mysql, controls

Is there a statement like Return used in Fortran and/or Basic to call a subroutine to perform some tasks and return the control back to the calling webpage if I am using PHP/MYSQL to gather some server data? I am relatively new to data crunching using Php/SQL so go easy on me, please! To my understanding, I can code my Php/MySql logic as a Php Function and insert the code

```
<?php 

function myfunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)
{
/* sql statements to get the data from the server
}

?>
```

My question is what is the right way to return to the control back to the calling webpage after the statement from which the call was initiated after the successful execution of the php/mysql statements embeded in the webpage with the php myfunction code? Thanks!

Comment: Um.... `exit;` I guess. Though your question doesn't make any sense and doesn't appear to show much understanding of how fundamentals such as HTTP request - response work. I would suggest trying to ask a specific question including what exactly you're trying to do, why, what you've tried, and what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: php has `return();` too

Comment: Thanks nogad and Jon for your prompt reply. I will try using the return(); command suggested by nogad to see if the control returns to the command immediately after the statement where the php function statement was inserted to give the control back to the web page invoking the function. It is like using the HTML Form to collect some user input, do necessary mysql queries and return the control back to the calling web page to display the reults in HTML table!